# Every Character and show referenced in Crisis On Infinite Earth?

Tags: character, reference, arrowverse, crossovers

The CW crossover for this year is called *Crisis on Infinite Earths* and most of the CW shows and characters are seen or said as a reference by someone.

So I am wondering if someone could explain which characters and shows are referenced.

The crossover is not over yet, it is taking a mid-break and will continue in January. The following are the shows I could identify

- The Flash
- The Arrow
- Supergirl
- Batwoman
- Legends of Tomorrow
- Black Lightning
- Lucifer
- Titans??
- Old Flash?

Comment: You only want for pre-existing character and show reference only not made up one?

Comment: I would like to know the made up ones too.. if there is any

Answer (score 9):

You are missing out few, will try to answer in chronology:

From Supergirl S05E08:

- **Tim Burton's Batman Movies:**  Alexander Knox (Robert Wuhl) cameo who was the first to report upon The Joker's crimes
- **Titans:** Hawk (Alan Ritchson) and Jason Todd (Curran Walters) cameo
- **Batman (1966 TV series):** Robin (Burt Ward) shouts "Holy Crimson Skies Of Death!"
- **Freedom Fighters: The Ray** We see Russell Tovey flying in his Ray costume.

Then, of course, we see **Supergirl**, **The Flash**, **Arrow**, **Batwoman** and **Legends of Tomorrow** characters

From Batwoman S01E09

- **Smallville:**  powerless retired Clark Kent and Lois Lane.
- **Superman Returns:** Brandon Routh Superman (costume from Kingdom Come TPB)
- **Batman:** Kevin Conroy as Batman in the future
- **Jonah Hex:** Johnathan Schaech as Jonah tries to prevent Oliver's resurrection in the Lazarus Pit

From The Flash S06E08

- **Birds of Prey (2002 TV series):** Helena Kyle Cameo
- **Lucifer:** Lucifer cameo
- **The Flash (1990 TV series):** Flash (John Wesley Shipp) appears
- **Black Lightning:** Black Lightning cameo

Comment: Tina Magee (Amanda Pays) appeared when 1990s Flash saw his life flash before his eyes, though I think that was a clip from the original 1990 series, so she didn't act in that episode. Do you think that one should be in the list?